# Handle to Matlab patch gets deleted automatically, how to create array of figure handles

Tags: arrays, matlab

```
figure;

for i=1:num
    h{i} = fill(c{i}(:,1), c{i}(:,2), 'b');
end

axis([0 500 0 700]);
daspect([1 1 1]);
hold on;
```

`c` is just a cell of 2D arrays that store x,y of the vertices of the polygons. I am trying to plot multiple polygons and store handles to them so that i can modify the polygons later.
But after `h{1}` stores the patch to the first polygon in second iteration `i=2`, `h{1}` gets deleted.

How can i store the various patches?

Comment: You need to call `hold on` in order for one plot object to not remove the previous ones

Comment: Ah! got it! Wrong placement of `hold on`